# Undefined reference in C with gcrypt.h

Tags: c, eclipse

I'm trying to use the library gcrypt.h but show this error:

> undefined reference to `gcry_md_get_algo_dlen'

The code is:

```
int algo = GCRY_MD_SHA1;                                
unsigned int hash_len = gcry_md_get_algo_dlen(algo); 
unsigned char hash[hash_len];
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: According to http://www.gossamer-threads.com/lists/gentoo/user/235371 you should have gcrypt 1.5 or later installed to use these functions, but http://cryptsetup.googlecode.com/svn-history/r510/trunk/lib/crypto_backend/crypto_gcrypt.c suggests it's available from 1.1.42 onwards.

Comment: How are you compiling/linking your program ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you have the most recent version of the library http://www.gnupg.org/download/#libgcrypt

If you have the right version make sure you added the library itself to your linker settings in Eclipse.

To do so:

Right-Click on your project -> Properties / C/C++Build / Settings / GCC C++ Linker / Libraries

There you add to libraries "gcrypt" ( you don't at the "lib" to it ) 
And also make sure that ( if the lib isnt under a system path ) you add the path where the library itself lies.

Comment: Thanks, I have gcrypt.h in /usr/include/ and add gcrypt.h as Right-Click on your project -> Properties / C/C++Build / Settings / GCC C++ Linker / Libraries and show the error: cannot find -lgcrypt.h                                                          Thanks you

Comment: Nono under the C++Linker/Libraries you dont add the header - there you just add "gcrypt" without the ".h" - you need to add the library also, not just the header.

Comment: Thanks you very much now all ok, but why i have to add the library gcrypt? and other no, as the library dirent. Excuse me for my English Thanks

Comment: The header just declare's all the function prototypes. If you only include the header, your compiler knows there are some functions but not who they're implemented. In the library itself there is, simply said, the code. So it's not just enough to add the header!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are facing a Linking Error (Undefined reference to a function)
You have included the header "gcrypt.h" but  the object file is not linked to your main file.
Library is NOT the same as the header (.h) file. C libraries are collections of compiled objects which are LINKED to your object code by the linker. Header files are lexically included by the preprocessor.

When you compile, you need to make sure that the libraries are where they're supposed to be AND the header files are where they're supposed to be. Either one can mess you up. Make sure that .o files are linked properly